# Use set content to create multiple output files

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script:

```
(Select-String -path c:\*.txt -Pattern 'searchstring').Line | set-content d:\output.txt
```

It works fine but the output file is too big. What I would like is for it to output multiple files so `output.txt` is the same number of files as is being read in with the wild card.

So:

```
c:\1.txt
c:\2.txt
c:\3.txt
```

Would output the matched lines to:

```
d:\1.txt
d:\2.txt
d:\3.txt
```

Comment: have you looked at the `.Filename` property of the objects returned by `Select-String`? you can group on that and then output to a new file based on the items in each group.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, to avoid ambiguity in general you'd have to group by `.Path`. I had considered a `Group-Object` solution, but it is more memory-intensive (and possibly also slower overall) than calling `Select-String` on each input file, and the solution isn't any shorter.

Comment: @mklement0 - the OP seems to indicate the source files will all be in one directory ... and the dest files will be in another. that seems to sidestep the need for `-Path`. [*grin*] however, i suspect you are correct about the likely RAM needs. i have noticed that piping from G-CI to S-S is notably slower than using S-S to grab the files directly, so  it may not be slower to use G-O in that situation.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, that's why I said _in general_. If you're interested in grouping matches by the specific files they came from, there's no reason to use `FileName` for grouping - it may work in this specific case, but you're asking for trouble in other cases. The speed tradeoff doesn't come from what you describe - there's virtually no difference between piping file-info objects vs. using `-Path` to a _single_ `Select-String` call - but comes from requiring _multiple_ `Select-String` calls. That is balanced against the processing (not just memory) overhead that grouping brings.

Comment: However, @Lee_Dailey, point taken re `FileName` (rather than robust `Path`) grouping with respect to making it easy to use `$_.Name` to get the file name for each group in order to form the output path; that said, `$_.Groups[0].FileName` gives you the same thing, and avoids the grouping pitfall.

Comment: @mklement0 - thank you for the clarification ... i do appreciate it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests, use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve the target files, then call `Select-String` on them one by one:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\*.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($lines = ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'SearchPattern').Line) {
      Set-Content -LiteralPath (Join-Path d:\ $_.Name) -Value $lines
    }
  }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly (or appears to be). The script has been running for 24hrs now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @sb5917; my pleasure.